# SSL secured account section, Subdirectory vs Subdomain

Tags: php, nginx, security, ssl, performance

I'm currently running Drupal on an nginx server, and I also have a separate user account system running on account.domain.com. I purchased a wildcard SSL certificate to protect the login form, but the SSL hasn't been set up yet, but I'm looking for your opinion on which system to use, subdirectory, or subdomain.

The user would go to the homepage, and press the sign in button. From there, they will be sent to either:

account.domain.com
or
domain.com/account

Which system would be:
1. More secure
2. Demand less requirements from the server
3. Easier to maintain and administer.

Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a sysadmin standpoint, the only difference is that you'd need a DNS record for the subdomain, but that only takes a minute to configure and you'd need to add a config to your webserver of choice to respond to requests on this subdomain. This is also trivial. Do whatever you prefer.

From the web development side of things, there are many pros and cons to a subdomain vs a directory, but that question has been answered time and again on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) so check there if this is a concern.